# Murmur3 hash different result between Python and Java implementation

Tags: java, python, guava, murmurhash

I have two different program that wish to hash same string using Murmur3 in Python and Java respectively.

Python version 2.7.9:

```python
mmh3.hash128('abc')
```

Gives 79267961763742113019008347020647561319L.

Java is Guava 18.0:

```java
HashCode hashCode = Hashing.murmur3_128().newHasher().putString("abc", StandardCharsets.UTF_8).hash();
```

Gives string "6778ad3f3f3f96b4522dca264174a23b", converting to BigInterger gives 137537073056680613988840834069010096699.

How to get same result from both?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how to get the same result from both:

```
byte[] mm3_le = Hashing.murmur3_128().hashString("abc", UTF_8).asBytes();
byte[] mm3_be = Bytes.toArray(Lists.reverse(Bytes.asList(mm3_le)));
assertEquals("79267961763742113019008347020647561319",
    new BigInteger(mm3_be).toString());
```

The hash code's bytes need to be treated as *little endian* but `BigInteger` interprets bytes as big endian. You were presumably using `new BigInteger(hex, 16)` to create the `BigInteger`, but the output of `HashCode.toString()` is actually a series of pairs of hexadecimal digits representing the hash bytes in the same order they're returned by `asBytes()` (little endian). (You can also reverse those pairs of hexadecimal to get a hex number that does produce the same result when passed to `new BigInteger(reversedHex, 16)`).

I think the documentation of `toString()` is somewhat confusing because of the way it refers to "big endian"; it doesn't actually mean that the output of the method is the hexadecimal number representing the bytes interpreted as big endian.

We have an open [issue](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1323) for adding `asBigInteger()` to `HashCode`.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is interested in the reverse answer, converting the python output to the Java output:

```
import mmh3
import string

char_array = '0123456789abcdef'
mumrmur = mmh3.hash_bytes('abc')

result = [f'{string.hexdigits[(char >> 4) & 0xf]}{string.hexdigits[char & 0xf]}' for char in mumrmur]
print(''.join(result))
```