# Murmurhash of different language version get different result

Tags: java, python, go, jedis, murmurhash

I've tried three version of murmurhash in java(jedis and guava), go and python. The result of java(guava),go and python version output same hash code but different with java(jedis).
All the murmurhash code are shown as follow. I'm confused about the result. I've seen this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932956/murmur3-hash-different-result-between-python-and-java-implementation) and use `Long.reverseBytes` in java, and still different with others. So what should I do to make all the output of murmurhash keep same. Thanks~

**1. java version(jedis)**

java gradle `compile group: 'redis.clients', name: 'jedis', version: '3.1.0'`

```java
import redis.clients.jedis.util.MurmurHash;

MurmurHash murmurhash = new MurmurHash();
long h = murmurhash.hash("foo");
System.out.println(h);
System.out.println(Long.reverseBytes(h));
```

**output:**

```
-7063922479176959649

6897758107479832477
```

**2. golang version**

```golang
import "github.com/spaolacci/murmur3"

foo := int64(murmur3.Sum64WithSeed([]byte("foo"), 0x1234ABCD))
fmt.Println(foo)
```

**output:**

```
-5851200325189400636
```

**3. python version**

`pip install mmh3`

```py
import mmh3

foo = mmh3.hash64('foo', seed=0x1234ABCD, signed=True)
print(foo)
```

**output:**

```
-5851200325189400636
```

**4. java(guava)**

java gradle `compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '28.0-jre'`

```java
import com.google.common.hash.Hashing

long foo = Hashing.murmur3_128(0x1234ABCD).hashString("foo", charset.forName("UTF-8")).asLong();
System.out.println(foo);
```

**output:**

```
-5851200325189400636
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**
*Jedis uses Murmur2 while the other libraries use Murmur3.*

---

I also fell for it while migrating some code from Java/Jedis to Golang.

The difference is due to different versions of murmur.
Jedis uses, up to this day, Murmur2 (see [source code](https://github.com/redis/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/util/MurmurHash.java#L21) and [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/redis.clients/jedis/latest/redis/clients/jedis/util/MurmurHash.html)), while the other above mentioned libraries use Murmur3.

Besides looking at the comments/code, I also verified this by using the [Murmur2 reference implementation](https://github.com/abrandoned/murmur2). Using the same seed and key leads to the exact same results as your Jedis example.

**Code Fragment:**

```
const char *key = "foo";

uint64_t result = MurmurHash64A(key, std::strlen(key), 0x1234ABCD);

std::cout << "  result (unsigned): " << result << std::endl;
std::cout << "    result (signed): " << (long) result << std::endl;
std::cout << "reversed byte order: " << __builtin_bswap64(result) << std::endl;
```

**Output:**

```
    result (unsigned): 11382821594532591967
      result (signed): -7063922479176959649
  reversed byte order:  6897758107479832477
```