# Murmur3 Hash Compatibility Between Go and Python

Tags: python, go, hash, murmurhash

We have two different libraries, one in Python and one in Go that need to compute murmur3 hashes identically. Unfortunately no matter how hard we try, we cannot get the libraries to produce the same result. It appears from [this SO question about Java and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932956/murmur3-hash-different-result-between-python-and-java-implementation) that compatibility isn't necessarily straight forward.

Right now we're using the [python mmh3](https://pypi.org/project/mmh3/) and [Go github.com/spaolacci/murmur3](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spaolacci/murmur3) libraries.

In Go:

```golang
hash := murmur3.New128()
hash.Write([]byte("chocolate-covered-espresso-beans"))
fmt.Println(base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil)))
// Output: cLHSo2nCBxyOezviLM5gwg
```

In Python:

```py
name = "chocolate-covered-espresso-beans"
hash = mmh3.hash128(name.encode('utf-8'), signed=False).to_bytes(16, byteorder='big', signed=False)
print(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hash).decode('utf-8').strip("="))
# Output: jns74izOYMJwsdKjacIHHA (big byteorder)

hash = mmh3.hash128(name.encode('utf-8'), signed=False).to_bytes(16, byteorder='little', signed=False)
print(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hash).decode('utf-8').strip("="))
# Output: HAfCaaPSsXDCYM4s4jt7jg (little byteorder)

hash = mmh3.hash_bytes(name.encode('utf-8'))
print(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hash).decode('utf-8').strip("="))
# Output: HAfCaaPSsXDCYM4s4jt7jg
```

In Go, `murmur3` returns a `uint64` so we assume `signed=False` in Python; however we also tried `signed=True` and did not get matching hashes.

We're open to different libraries, but are wondering if there is something wrong with either our Go or Python methodologies of computing a base64 encoded hash from a string. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Here is a gist for various testing we're doing if it helps: https://gist.github.com/bbengfort/fed9f92142b31b0261fc71fdb0d168a5

Comment: There are two different versions of the murmurhash3 algorithm, one optimized for x86 and one optimized for x64, that produce different hash values. It's possible you're not using the same algorithm on both platforms.

Comment: Good thought; I assumed that the x64 optimizations would be used on my machine but perhaps I should check that out in more detail.

Comment: Don't they both produce ints? Why don't you look at those, instead of adding multiple steps to turn them into strings? Maybe the difference is actually in those additional steps...

Comment: Your Go code isn't valid.

Comment: Ah, sorry missed closing parentheses - it is fixed now. We did check to see if the encoding was the problem, using long decimal, hex, and base64 encodings of the 128-bit number that was returned and we were still having the problem with non-matching hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That first Python result is almost right.

```py
>>> binascii.hexlify(base64.b64decode('jns74izOYMJwsdKjacIHHA=='))
b'8e7b3be22cce60c270b1d2a369c2071c'
```

In Go:

```golang
    x, y := murmur3.Sum128([]byte("chocolate-covered-espresso-beans"))
    fmt.Printf("%x %x\n", x, y)
```

Results in:

```
70b1d2a369c2071c 8e7b3be22cce60c2
```

So the order of the two words is flipped. To get the same result in Python, you can try something like:

```py
name = "chocolate-covered-espresso-beans"
hash = mmh3.hash128(name.encode('utf-8'), signed=False).to_bytes(16, byteorder='big', signed=False)
hash = hash[8:] + hash[:8]
print(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hash).decode('utf-8').strip("="))
# cLHSo2nCBxyOezviLM5gwg
```

Comment: Good eye; not sure how you spotted that! I guess both Go and Python's murmur128 are using 2 64-bit unsigned ints but returning them in different orders. Seems like that could cause a few problems with the base specification.

Comment: It's become one of those "check first" things for me after dealing with it so many times in the past. Seeing the data in hex makes these kind of issues easier to spot.

Comment: I've opened issues in both the Go and Python repositories to see if there is a way we can find a fix wrt to the murmur3 reference code.